# Splitting a string starts with $

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to split a string like "$ 12,9608,03" and just want the numbers and convert to an integer.
For splitting how should I use split() in java as there is a space after the $ sign.

Tried with following:

```
String[] arr_1=mystring.Split(“[\$, ] “);
String array1=arr_1[0];
Sopln(array1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want, I believe, using this:

```
String splited = "$ 12,9608,03".replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```

Then you will have splitted only the numbers by commas, but as `String`. Then you can use, for each `String` you got, `Integer.valueOf()` method.

Answer (score 0):

use space in regular experssion to split the string.

```
String[] split = str.split("( )");
System.out.println(split[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] splitted = mystring.split(" ");
String numb = splitted[1];
```

Just split on the whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Just like that:

```
String[] arr_1=mystring.Split("$");
String array1=arr_1[0].trim();
Sopln(array1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some fine answers here, to finish off the whole question

> and convert to an integer

Here you are:

```
String myString = "$ 12,9608,03";
String[] splitted = myString.split(" ");
int numb = Integer.parseInt(splitted[1].replaceAll(",", ""));

System.out.println(numb);
```

Answer (score 0):

To take just the digits, you'd do better with replace:

```
mystring.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "")
```

The first parameter is a regex that matches anything but a digit. So this will return you just the number

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop being insane.  Almost everything you will ever do (applies to all readers) has already been done (often better) by the Apache Commons project.
2. Read the [Apache Commons StringUtils API page](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html), pay attention to the `RemoveAll` method.
3. Use the `StringUtils.RemoveAll` method.
4. Convert the output from the `StringUtils.RemoveAll` method to an int;
   catch any exceptions and handle them appropriately.